# Bring back the accounts tab

Tags: script

[The accounts tab has been removed from all SE sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/128368/178438). Here's how to get it back for those of you with muscle memory:

### Installation

- [Click to install](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/raw/master/StackExchange/accountstab.user.js) (Chrome or Firefox+Greasemonkey only)
- [Source code](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/blob/master/StackExchange/accountstab.user.js)

<sup>I'm new to Git and to userscripts, so any comments would be appreciated</sup>

Comment: For me, this only works if the summary tab is the active one. The internals of the page differ for the other tabs, so there's no `user-panel-footer` element to be found, which is why it doesn't work.

Comment: @tak I know, I've been meaning to tweak that by copying the SE.com userid from the profile. Was a quick  hack. I'll fix this tomorrow.

Comment: @takrl [Got bored and fixed it](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/commit/5d08a9054baf701d2b0bd302e25eecb8b578cdf2#StackExchange/accountstab.user.js) ;-)